# Nested object and array destructuring

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to convert an object to a leaner version using destructuring.

My object includes a nested array which also contains objects, from this array I would only like a few fields.

I can do the nested object destructuring fine, and the array destructuring fine but not together?

My current try looks like this:

```
var data = {
    title: "title1",
    bar: "asdf",
    innerData: [
       {
        title: "inner-title1",
        foo: "asdf"
       },
       {
        title: "inner-title2",
        foo: "asdf"
       }
    ]
};

var { title, innerData: [ { title} ] } = data;

console.log(title);

for (var { title} of innerData) {
  console.log(title);
}
```

But get a message saying `innerData is not defined.`

The outcome I would like might be:

```
{
    title: "title1",
    innerData: [
       {
        title: "inner-title1"
       },
       {
        title: "inner-title2"
       }
    ]
};
```

Comment: Only do `var { title, innerData } = data;` to get the `innerData` array in the variable

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can adjust the variable name to an identifier other than defined `innerData` ; use `.map()` or `JSON.stringify()`, `JSON.parse()` to filter `title` property from `innerData` objects

```
var {title, titles = data.innerData.map(o => ({title:o.title}))} = data;
```

to maintain `innerData` variable name you can use array destructuring of object

```
var [title, innerData] = [data.title, data.innerData.map(o => ({title:o.title}))];
```

using `JSON.stringify()`, `JSON.parse()`

```
var [title, innerData] = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify([data.title, data.innerData], ["title"]));
```

---

Edit

If requirement is to create an array containing all `title` properties within `data` you can use `JSON.stringify()` with replacer array set to `["title"]`, `JSON.parse()`, spread element

```js
var data = {
    title: "title1",
    bar: "asdf",
    innerData: [
       {
        title: "inner-title1",
        foo: "asdf"
       },
       {
        title: "inner-title2",
        foo: "asdf"
       }
    ]
};

var innerData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify([data, ...data.innerData], ["title"]))
                                                                      
console.log(innerData);
```

Answer (score 12):

Your destructuring doesn't do what you think.

```
var { title, innerData: [ { title} ] } = data;
```

is (essentially) equivalent to

```
var title = data.title;
var title = data.innerData[0].title;
```

Destructuring pulls out individual values, it will not map through the array for you. You'll need to do that manually if that is what you want.

Comment: I did spot that I thought perhaps there was a way that I could iterate them in one step. cheers.

Answer (score 1):

As per @loganfsmyth suggested, I will do it in two steps.

```
var { title } = data;

for (var { title } of data.innerData) {
  console.log( title );
}
```

***Edit: my final solution to build a new json object from the old***

```
const request = { innerData: [] };

({ title } = this.data);

for (const { title} of this.data.innerData) {
    request.innerData.push({
        title
    });
}
```

Comment: Note, `data` at Answer if different from `data` at Question; `foo` properties are not present at `data.innerData`. Is requirement to assign `title` to `data.title`, `innerData` as array of values corresponding to value of `title` of `data.innerData` without `foo` property?